# Combining results of two queries

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, querydsl

I'm using Kibana v6.1.1 and trying to get within one `GET` request two different queries in order to use the "must" or "should" terms more than once. 
When I run this query under "Dev Tools" in the Kibana, it works. 
When I want to apply this "double query" (without the GET line of course) under "Discover"->"Add a filter"->"Edit filter"->"Edit Query DSL", it doesn't accept the syntax `{}` in order to create an 'OR' between the queries.
It is necessary that these two "must" terms will be separated but stay in the same filter.

```
GET _my_index/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [{
        ...
      }]
    }
  }
}
{}
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [{
        ...
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

P.S.
Using the `simple_query_string` doesn't seem to solve the problem and so far, I couldn't find the way to combine these two queries.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you actually want to achieve. Use the following if at least one of the `should`s has to match (there is an implicit `minimum_should_match` if there are no other conditions, but you can also set an explicit value for that):

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        {
          ...
        },
        {
          ...
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to run independent queries, use a [multi search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html).

Comment: Thanks for commenting xeraa. The problem is that one query gives me certain results for the combination of specific "must" - "should" - "must_not", while the other query needs a different combination of "must" - "should" - "must_not". They can't exist together in the same query. What I need is the results of both queries. I've achieved this result when I wrote the query under "dev tools" as I wrote above, but couldn't achieve it under "discover"